# Difference between jquery find() method for $("selector").find and $("selector").contents().find()

Tags: jquery, html

I have two ways for navigation by getting the elements' offsets:

```
 $("#selector").contents().find('#'+list1).each(function(){
     var offset= $(this).offset();
 }); 


 $("#selector").find('#'+list1).each(function(){
     var offset= $(this).offset();
 });
```

There are thousands of links. I have found with both codes, a few links are returning the offset as `0`. What is the perfect way to make it fool proof?

**Note:** All nodes are displayed as `block` and are present in the selector `div`. I can't use 
`document.getElementById()`.

Comment: Both are same.. both are gonna search for the descendants..

Comment: Using `.contents()` followed by `.find()` seems redundant.

Comment: Though they may not give the same results.

Comment: btw you don't need to issue an `.each()` after an ID selector: that should be unique.

Answer (score 2):

Those two are different in what they will search. If the element you're trying to `find()` is one of the elements returned by `contents()`, that item won't be returned.

See this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ta2QJ/

```
<div id="topDiv">
    <div id="targetDiv">
        <div id="innerDiv">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
console.log($('#topDiv').find('#targetDiv').length); // 1
console.log($('#topDiv').contents().find('#targetDiv').length); // 0
```

However, if the element you're trying to find isn't returned by `.contents()`, there's no difference. You're just pulling the current element's direct children, then calling `.find()` on those elements.

Comment: Its a nice example. I didn't think of this. +1

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
var offset = $('#' + list1).offset();
```

The id attribute must be unique, if not, you should take care of that.

`.contents()` is only really useful for finding elements in iframes and getting text nodes and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Find will be deeper.   It can find not just children, but childrens children.

Contents is most similar to children, with the exception that contents will also fetch text nodes in the immediate subset.   That being said, i guess you can say that contents, like children will only go 1 tier, where as find, is doing a selector where the selected object is the root.

Does that make sense?

Calling:    contents().find("beta") will essentially just set the root down 1 tier, actually, it will carry out the selector for ALL children.

exmaple:

```
a = $(".myDiv");
b = $(".myDiv").contents().find("li");
c = $(".myDiv").find("li");
```

here you will see that it will try to find the result of the array of contents, and then call find on it, which means it will run down those respective trees.

just `find()`, will do the exact same thing.

The real difference is the scope of what is "root" in regards to the object.  For b, each item in `contents()` array is its own root being searched, where as the other way, `.myDiv` is the root.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").contents().find()
```

Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes and finding the content.

---

```
$("selector").find()
```

Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.